# Store the tooltip information after plotly click event in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, ggplotly

I have the shiny app below in which I want to be able to click on a stacked bar chart and then be able to print below the information that are displayed in the tooltip box. For example if I click on the blue section of the 1st bar I will get `D0.5, 6.8, VC.`

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(DT)
library(crosstalk)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plt"),
  textOutput("tooltip")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  df2 <- data.frame(supp=rep(c("VC", "OJ"), each=3),
                    dose=rep(c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),2),
                    len=c(6.8, 15, 33, 4.2, 10, 29.5))
  

  output$plt<-renderPlotly({
    # Stacked barplot with multiple groups
    p<-ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity")
    ggplotly(p)
    
  })
  
  
}
```